# Issue Getting Physical Address in Kernel Module - Can't MMAP to that address

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am implementing DMA through memory mapped registers and need the physical address of the buffers used to pass on to the DMA device.

I allocate my memory using a kernel module, then pass the physical address on to the userspace application driving the DMA. I have tried with and without the Page Shift.

```
float* buffer = (float*) kcalloc(512, sizeof(float), GFP_DMA); //allocate physical memory for DMA
unsigned long physAddr = virt_to_phys(buffer) >> PAGE_SHIFT;
```

When I write these addrs to my DMA device no data moves - and when I attempt to mmap to these addrs from /dev/mem they result in invalid pointers (segfaults on read).

How should I be getting these addresses for the allocated memory?

Comment: Get familiar with DMA mapping API. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/DMA-API.txt

Comment: For `dma_alloc_coherent`, the DMA handle passed out via the 3rd parameter (a `dma_addr_t *` is effectively the physical address for the buffer as far as DMA transfers are concerned.

Comment: Thank you both! I'm looking into that and will swap over to that method for buffer allocation. Will post a full answer once I get it sorted.

Comment: @IanAbbott, first of all it’s a bus address, and the memory behind this address may or may not be present. CPU should operate over virtual address, the one returned by the function itself IIRC.